# How is the order of subject and verb decided on "Here/There ~" sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-order

In these sentences:

> Here she is.
>
> Here are our parents.
>
> Here is your book.

I don't understand why the first sentence takes the subject-verb order while the other two use an inversion.

Is it because the first one uses a subject pronoun? What is the rule of the order of the sentence on "Here/There ~" sentence? (and is there any difference of rules between "here" and "there"?)

Comment: What do you mean? You could have written *here is she*, *here our parents are* and *here your book is*. You just didn't. Different forms may be more or less common than others, but there's nothing preventing you from using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is probably due to usage and not a "***rule***", this often happens in English.  When using pronouns, the emphasis goes with the pronoun, so you might say

> Here are **our parents**.

but also

> Here **they** are.
>   **They** are here.

and also

> Where is **Deborah**?
>   Where is **she**?
>   **She** is here.
>   Here **she** is.